# What are the ways to write latex for internet pages such that latex equations are not accessible?

Tags: latex, mathjax, mathml, jqmath

I've heard of html (of course), mathml, mathjax, jsmath, jqmath... I would like to be able to post latex in internet pages such that the formulas cannot at all be accessible. I would like to avoid resorting to pictures of formulas included in html, I know that latex source is accessible when one uses mathjax, and I find mathml to complex, as I already have tons of latex sources that I want to recycle without rewriting anything, or at minima. What could I do ?

Comment: post them as images. anything you see in a browser is downloadable (it HAS to be, so the user can see it), so if you don't want your mathml/latex source visible, then render it to an image.

Comment: @MarcB "I would like to avoid resorting to pictures of formulas included in html" --> so you state that avoid this is impossible ? "anything you see in a browser is downloadable" --> is this really true ?

Comment: pretty much. for something tob e visible in the browser, it HAS to be downloaded. so either you send out the markup and the browser renders it, or you pre-render and send out a picture of it. there's no other way. if you send out the markup, then there is NOTHING you can do to prevent the user from getting at it.

Comment: Even with javascript encryption of html files ?...

Comment: and now you've changed it from "hiding latex" to "hiding decryption password", which isn't really much of a change at all. there is NOTHING you can to do protect data once it's reached the user. at some point it has to be decrypted to be useable, and that's when it can be intercepted.